# Check whether an element occurs in a list using recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

```
def check(x,num,i):
    for n in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] == num:
            return True
        else:
            return(check(x,num,i+1))
    return False
def User(x,num):
    return(check(x,num,0))
```

User([2,6,1,9,7,3],5,0)
this should out put false since 5 is not in the list

checks whether an element occurs in a list recursively

so for example:

Input: a list L read from the keyboard, for example L = [2,6,1,9,7,3]
 an element e, for example e = 9

but for some reason, i get an error when the number is not in the list

Comment: This shouldn't even work. `range(len(x)-)` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the traceback for the error so we can help you find and elimate the problem!

Comment: FYI: You can use `num in x` to check if a `num` is included in a list `x`. (not recursive but certainly more performant).

Comment: using "in" would be too easy. These are the type of questions I will get in my exam in January  they will want me to use recursion .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beauty (and purpose) of recursion is that you do **not** need the loop:

```
def check(x, num, i):
    if not x[i:]:  # index past length
        return False
    if x[i] == num:
        return True
    return(check(x, num, i+1))
```

You can also do without the index parameter:

```
def check(x, num):
    if not x:
        return False
    return x[0] == num or check(x[1:], num)
```

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: check([2,6,1,9,7,3],5,0) it should output false since it not in the list. But, you get a error

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain what " if not x[i:]" this checks ?

Comment: `x[i:]` is the slice of `x` beginning at index `i` all the way to the end. If `i >= len(x)` that slice will be an empty list and thus have `False` truthiness.

Comment: Thank you for your time :) and your explanation.

Comment: If you like short functions, you can also use `return False if not lst else item == lst[0] or check(item, lst[1:])` in the second `check` function.

Comment: @MSeifert True. However, removing one `return` and a colon for the price of an `else` would not warrant the loss of readability, especially for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you're doing, but this is a bizarre combination of recursion and iteration. If you're going to use recursion, it's worthwhile, at least for a basic recursive problem like this, to avoid iteration. Try something like this

```
def check(x, num, i = 0):
    if i >= len(x):
        return False
    elif x[i] == num:
        return True
    else:
        return check(x, num, i + 1)
```

This solution will work perfectly fine and is tail recursive so it will work quickly and optimally.

The way this works is it checks if the index, `i`, is out of bounds. If so, then it returns `False`. If it is in bounds, it checks if `x[i]` is equal to the number. If so, it returns `True`. If it is not, it returns `check` with the index increased and thus the recursion works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your for loop doesn't make any sense. You never use that n and never go into the loop a second time, as you always return something in the first iteration. The return statement after the for loop is also unreachable, so your code could as well be

```
def check(x,num,i):
    if x[i] == num:
        return True
    else:
        return(check(x,num,i+1))
```

Then the actual issue is, that if you have a list with 5 elements for example, which does not contain the element searched for, you ask what the 6th is, although there is no 6th element, thus the error. You'd have to check whether the list contains 6 elements. So you check whether it has more than 5, return false if it does and continue if it doesn't. (Alternatively you could also check this at the start of the whole function)

```
def check(x,num,i):
    if x[i] == num:
        return True
    else:
        if len(num)>i:
            return False
        else:
            return(check(x,num,i+1))
```

What you've done then is nothing but a overcomlicated, recursive for-Loop. You just increase i and compare, until you find the element or i is bigger than the list length. So this is equivalent to

```
def check(x,num):
    for i in range(len(num)):
        if x[i]==num:
            return True
    return False
```

It is very important that the `return False` is AFTER the for-Loop, as you only return, if you didn't find the element, even after iterating over the WHOLE list.

Also you can avoid indices. With a for-Loop you can directly iterate over the elements in a list:

```
def check(x,num):
    for elem in num:
        if elem==num:
            return True
    return False
```

This makes the variable elem become every element in you list, one after another.

Comment: second one doesn't work

Comment: oops, swapped the second if/else statement. Fixed.